# Partition directories into subdirectories based on directory name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Background: a client's website stores user profile photos and other attachments into a single flat folder `/user/images/*user_id*`. They recently hit the directory limit (`echo */ | wc` echoes `31998`, file system is ext3) so I need to split them up into smaller chunks.

The user folders in `/user/images` are based on the user ID stored in the DB. There are a few non-number based directories which are to ignore.

I created a small bash script which works fine in my test environment but I would like to have your opinion on this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for D in *; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then # check if it's a directory

        echo "Directory: ${D}"

        if [ "${D}" -eq "${D}" ] 2>/dev/null # check if directory is a valid integer / number based
        then
            pre=${D:0:1} # $pre = first letter of the directory name
            echo "Subdir: ${pre}"

            if [[ ! -d "${pre}" ]] # check if directory $pre exists
            then
                mkdir "${pre}" # directory $pre does not exist, create it
                echo "Created subdir ${pre}..."
            fi

            mv "${D}" "${pre}" # move $d into $pre
            echo "Moved ${D} into ${pre}..."

        else
            echo "Directory: ${D} is not number based, i.e. not based on a user id. Skipping..."
        fi
    fi
done
```

I would welcome any suggestions or optimization tips before I run this on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mkdir -p` to avoid checking if the directory exist, unless you really need the `Created subdir ${pre}` message.

Since you are hitting the directory limit, maybe you want to create the new directories somewhere else, moving stuff into it (thus creating space in the full directory) and finally move the new directory back in the original directory.

Also, using the `-n` switch for `mv` may help preventing accidental loss of data.

One last thought - the star wildcard expansion may exceed the maximum bash line length. If it is the case you may pipe the output of `ls -1` into a while based loop that reads the input line by line.